# file downloading in sharepoint

Tags: development, web-part, document-library, wss-3.0

I've created a web-part. I've added few documents to it.
I'm implementing download functionality. I want file download dialog.
My code is like this.

```
DownloadItem(SPListItem item)
{
   // Get physical path of the file
   string itemPath = MapPathSecure(item.File.Url);

   HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
   HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + item.File.Name);            
   HttpContext.Current.Response.TransmitFile(itemPath);
   HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

> This throws an error : "Could not find a part of the path 'Path to the
>   document'. The path does not exist. I know that Sharepoint documents
>   are not located on the hard disk. Am I missing something here ?

How do I get this code to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I slightly modified the code like this and it worked :)

```
byte[] data = item.File.OpenBinary();           
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + item.File.Name);
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Thanks alot for this user [Upload/Delete/Download from Document Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20358/Uploading-Deleting-and-Downloading-a-File-from-Sha?msg=4528903#_rating)

Comment: Any idea how to do a page post back after file down load. I have a similar WP documents showing up in a SPGridView. On a LinkButton click i download the document. Only the first download works. So i was thinking to do a page post back afterwards. How to do that ?